# Is it good to serve static files under Rails' public folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, frontend, static-files

I have a front-end single page app written in AngularJS, and I want to use Rails to build a back-end API.

I wonder if it is OK to put all front-end files in Rails' `public` folder, and mount all Rails' API routes on `api/xxxx`. In this way, I can save developers' efforts so they don't need to run two server when developing (front-end server and back-end rails' server). Also, I don't need to care about Rails' assets pipeline. I can use totally pure front-end solution to optimize fron-tend application. All I need to do is just put them into one single applications.

Is there any drawback of such design?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that perfectly fine.  In fact, this is what `rake assets:precompile` does.